# How can send a Chinese Language SMS using gsmsendsms via GSM on Ubuntu 13.10 in PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, sms, gsm

I am trying to send a Chinese characters SMS via GSM USB Modem on Ubuntu 13.10
Q1:
Here is my code :

```
<?php echo system("gsmsendsms -d /dev/ttyACM7 -b 115200 13330925583 '你怎么样？'");?><br>
```

Then, sending is successed! But the characters is breaked.
How can send UTF8 characters clearly?

Q2:
I am using GSM USB Modem 8 port. i.e. ttyACM0 - ttyACM7
I found a code :

```
$fp=fopen('COM6', '+r');<br>
fputs($this->fp, "AT\r");<br>
```

.....

So, Is it possible :

```
$fp=fopen('ttyACM7', '+r');<br>
fputs($this->fp, "AT\r");<br>
```

....

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First you should patch gsmsendsms to support unicode (google gsmsendsms.patch)

```
 $apt-get source gsm-utils
 goto dir ./gsmlib-1.10/apps/ and
    $patch -p0 < gsmsendsms.patch
 $./configure && make
```

Second then use command

```
  $sudo /temp/gsmlib-1.10/apps/gsmsendsms  -u -d /dev/ttyACM0  13218647024 4e2d56fd
```

note: 4e2d56fd is unicode of chinese word "中国",a simple convert unicode you could use

```
  $sudo /temp/gsmlib-1.10/apps/gsmsendsms  -u -d /dev/ttyACM0  13218647024   $(printf "%x" "'中") $(printf "%x" "'国")
```

it's ok